# Obtener atributos de una clase sin ordenar alfabéticamente en Java (o Kotlin)

Tags: java, kotlin

Mi idea es obtener todos los atributos de una clase a partir de una instancia de un objeto de esa clase, pero al obtener la colección de atributos, me las almacena por orden alfabético y quiero que me lo devuelva por el orden que están definidos en el constructor.

Esta es mi clase:

```
class Empresa(override var id: Long = Long.MIN_VALUE, var uuid: String = "", var nombre : String = "")
```

Y al hacer:

```
var atributos = Empresa().javaClass.kotlin.memberProperties.toString()
```

Me devuelve:

```
[id, nombre, uuid]
```

Y la idea es que devuelva tal cual esté definido en el constructor (que no me los ordene alfabéticamente):

```
[id, uuid, nombre]
```

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que no es posible.Y no te los devuelve ordenados alfabéticamente, simplemente no tienen un orden concreto, este caso es una coincidencia. Puedes ver la [documentación de `getDeclaredFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields--) de java, que dice claramente:

> The elements in the returned array are not sorted and are not in any particular order.

Traducido:

> Los elementos en el array devuelto no están clasificados y no están en ningún orden particular.

**Editado**

Al parecer,a pesar de lo que dice la documentación, `getDeclaredFields` si que devuelve normalmente los campos en el orden de declaración (ver [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5004929/579895)). De todas maneras, esto no es fiable al 100%, y probablemente lo mejor sea no fiarse de este orden y comprobar el nombre de los campos.

Comment: Justo esa función sí te la devuelve en el orden en los que los declaras, debe ser que el método de Kotlin `memberProperties` sí te la ordena alfabéticamente. Edita la pregunta para darla como la solución.

Comment: @IbrahimHernándezJorge La documentación de Java es específica. Yo no basaría el funcionamiento de mi programa en un comportamiento que los ingenieros de Java se toman la molestia de remarcar que no está asegurado.

Comment: @IbrahimHernándezJorge no me fiaría yo mucho. He enlazado a una respuesta de [so] donde se dice que si parece devolverlos en orden,pero yo me andaría con cuidado :)

Comment: Pero la pregunta no hablaba del orden del constructor? Los parámetros de los constructores si tienen orden